# Detecting overlapping objects using matlab

Tags: matlab, object-detection

I am currently using the matlab function 'bwboundaries' to detect objects in a binary image and to obtain the coordinates of each object. However this function is not accurate when detecting objects that overlap in the image because the overlapped objects are considered as one object when the boundary is drawn  . Can anyone guide me to a improved method to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Add image examples to better illustration.

Answer (score 0):

[bwboundaries](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html) works for binary objects, and produces contours of the binary sets in the image. Overlapping objects are connected sets and thus the operator bwboundaries will produce the contour of the total connected object. For overlapping objects one either needs different labeling or a way to decompose the overlapping connected set into two different objects. This needs a different operation to separate the objects, this might be a geometric criterion, like shape, convexity, perimeter, etc. An example here is provided for [overlapping circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170901/how-to-detect-overlapping-circles-and-fill-color-accordingly). Another example with [cells](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/05/23/detecting-circles-in-an-image/)